# Is $I:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z},x\mapsto \lfloor x \rfloor$ continuous? $\mathbb{Z}$ is endowed with the subspace topology.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'd like to say that it isn't.

Consider the set $\{1\}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, where $k$ is some integer. It is open because it equals $(0.5,1.5)\cap \mathbb{Z}$, and $(0.5,1.5)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

If we take $I^{-1}(\{1\})$, we get $[1,2)$, which isn't open in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, the function isn't continuous.

Comment: You're right.${}$

Comment: You can even show that every continuous map $f$ to $\Bbb Z$ is constant. For if an integers $k$ is in the image of $f$,  then $f^{-1}(k)$ is non-empty and both open and closed, and the only such subset of $\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb R$ itself.

Comment: Is that only true when $\mathbb{Z}$ is endowed with the subspace topology?

Comment: It is true when $Z$ is equipped with any topology making it a discrete space.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, as then every set is both open and closed. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right.

More generally, let $X$ be connected and $Y$ be discrete. A map $f: X \rightarrow Y$  is continuous if and only if it is constant.